# D3D12CreateDevice(pAdapter, D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_12_0) ISSUE

Tags: directx12

I'm getting this error when I compile this code.

D3D12CreateDevice(pAdapter, D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_12_0,
IID_PPV_ARGS(&pDevice)).
Error! No such Interface supported

I've got a rtx 2060 GPU installed in my computer.
All my GPU drivers are up to date.
I've got the windows 10 version 1803(OS Build 17134.590)
I've got visual studio 2017 installed and used to compile my code.

Here is the code I'm trying to compile. 
https://github.com/acmarrs/IntroToDXR

What, in the hell is this error man its so stupid.
I've been stuck for over 6 damn hours man.
Any help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your card & driver may support DirectX 12 (the API) but may not support the Direct3D Hardware Feature Level 12.0 feature level. Most of the sample code for DirectX 12 uses `D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0` as the minimum required hardware because that's the one that's most often supported.

See [Anatomy of Direct3D 12 Create Device](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2016/08/16/anatomy-of-direct3d-12-create-device/) and [Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/direct3d12/hardware-feature-levels)

Comment: So, can my gpu 2060 rtx card allow me to compile dxr ray casting code and is there ray tracing sample code out there that I can compile without the use of the direct3d hardware feature Level 12.0 feature level.??

Comment: Also, this is not in my question but Can you do ray casting in d3d12 with a dynamic linker that calls the exe as a injection method or is it only a win32 application d3d12 ray casting support feature.

Comment: The NVidia 2600 RTX card is a "Turing" card so it should work, although as I said it may only support a lower Direct3D hardware feature level. Can't help on the injection question, but you can try this [basic sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Xbox-ATG-Samples/tree/master/PCSamples/Raytracing/SimpleRaytracingTriangle_PC12).

Comment: Thanks, for the help Chuck WalBourn much appreciated.